# hacer que una base de datos en producción tenga la misma estructura que una base de datos de prueba

Tags: sql-server

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web con base de datos sql server, la cuestión es que uso dos bases de datos, una de pruebas y otra es la es la que esta en producción, entonces en el desarrollo de la aplicación creo o modifico tablas en la base de datos de prueba y al pasarla a producción es posible que se me pase alguna modificación que haya hecho y afecte la aplicación, mi pregunta es  ¿hay alguna forma o script que verifique la base de datos de prueba y haga el arreglo en la base de datos en producción?

Comment: hay aplicaciones de pago como [SQL Compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/), yo por lo regular valido con Visual Studio, desde el menú Herramientas > SQL Server > Nueva Comparación de Esquemas.

Comment: Puedes usar las aplicaciones de capa de datos. Harán tu trabajo más sencillo aunque requieren un poco de esfuerzo para configurarlas. [https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/data-tier-applications?view=sql-server-ver15]

Comment: Yo hago todas las modificaciones a los esquemas a través de scripts y, en los proyectos que están bajo mi control en este aspecto, tengo definido un proceso para llevar los cambios de desarrollo a pruebas y luego a producción a medida que se va haciendo el despliegue de las modificaciones que se realizan a los sistemas. Esto hace innecesario comparar los esquemas, pues nunca son iguales, pero siempre están a punto con lo que deben tener. Hay soluciones comerciales, como RedGate que pueden hacer esta tarea por ti: https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/